# Rails AJAX autocomplete an entire form based on one field entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

I am working on a rails application and I am very new to using javascript and AJAX.

Following the instructions here: https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete

I just implemented an autocomplete for one of the fields on my form.

Here is the form I'm working with:
[image]

What I want to do now, is when the user selects the auto complete, I want the remainder of the Company fields to be populated with the objects corresponding values.

I understand this will require some sort of additional javascript and AJAX to achieve.

The javascript function I am using for the autocomplete is:

```
$(function() {
    var companies = <%Company.all.collect{|company| company.name}%>
    $( "#jobCompany" ).autocomplete({
      source: companies
    });
  });
```

And the code for my form is:

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :date, :value=>Time.now %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value=>current_user.id %>

   <%= f.fields_for :company, @company do |company| %>
      <%= company.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_company_name_companies_path, placeholder: "Company Name" %>
      <%= company.text_field :phone, placeholder: "Company Phone" %>
      <%= company.text_field :street, placeholder: "Street" %>
      <%= company.text_field :city, placeholder: "City" %>
      <%= company.select :state, options_for_select(@states, @states[4]) %>
      <%= company.text_field :zip, placeholder: "Zip" %>
      <%= company.text_field :email, placeholder: "Company Email" %>
      <%= company.text_field :website, placeholder: "Company Website" %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What I imagine, is I will need some sort of AJAX to get the company object id from the autocomplete, then using that object populate the remaining fields.

As I said I am very new to javascript and AJAX. Can anyone give me some tips on how to approach implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was simpler than I expected.

After digging through the documentation of the Gem, I found how to use the `extra_data` and `update_elements` functions.

In the Company controller you add:

```
autocomplete :company, :name, :extra_data => [:phone, :street, :city, :zip, :email, :website]
```

And in the view you give each extra element an id:

```
<%= company.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_company_name_companies_path, 
                                            :update_elements => {:id => '#id_element',
                                                                 :phone => '#phone_element',
                                                                 :street => '#street_element',
                                                                 :city => '#city_element',
                                                                 :zip => '#zip_element',
                                                                 :email => '#email_element',
                                                                 :website => '#website_element'}, placeholder: "Company Name" %>
```

Then on each individual field you include the `:id`

```
<%= company.text_field :phone, id: 'phone_element', placeholder: "Company Phone" %>
<%= company.text_field :street, id: 'street_element', placeholder: "Street" %>
<%= company.text_field :city, id: 'city_element', placeholder: "City" %>
<%= company.text_field :zip, id: 'zip_element', placeholder: "Zip" %>
<%= company.text_field :email, id: 'email_element', placeholder: "Company Email" %>
<%= company.text_field :website, id: 'website_element', placeholder: "Company Website" %>
```

Now when the user autocompletes the Name field, it uses all the extra data it got back and places their values in the corresponding fields with the right id.

No extra AJAX or javascript needed, the gem handles it all behind the scenes for you.